# Tkinter multiple Radiobutton groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a settings window, with multiple groups of TkInter `Radiobutton`s. They should modify a text variable that I can work with later on.

I have the following code:

```
# radiobutton group 1
settingSort = ""
settingSortRadio1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(settingsWindow, text="Frequency", variable=settingSort, value="freq")
settingSortRadio1.select()
settingSortRadio1.pack()
settingSortRadio2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(settingsWindow, text="Alphabetical", variable=settingSort, value="alpha")
settingSortRadio2.pack()

#radiobutton group 2
settingAnalyseRadio1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(settingsWindow, text="Word frequency", variable=settingAnalyse, value="wfreq")
settingAnalyseRadio1.select()
settingAnalyseRadio1.pack()
settingAnalyseRadio2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(settingsWindow, text="Letter frequency", variable=settingAnalyse, value="lfreq")
settingAnalyseRadio2.pack()
```

However, these buttons all seem to be part of the same group still. Selecting a button in group 1 will deselect all others in the window (including in group 2), and vice versa.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work because you need to use a [variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instead of what you did.

I mean, you need to change this line:

```
settingSort = ""
```

to:

```
settingSort = tkinter.StringVar()
```

Then [you need to initialize](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm) `settingSort` according to your specific need.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're not using the in built variable classes from tkinter.

You need to do something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()

var1.set(0)
var2.set(0)

Radiobutton(root, text = "group1", variable = var1, value = 0).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text = "group1", variable = var1, value = 1).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text = "group2", variable = var2, value = 0).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text = "group2", variable = var2, value = 1).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Let's break this down to make it easier to understand.

```
var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
```

So above we create two `StringVar()` variables. As far as you need to be concerned these are just *"containers"* which store the value of specific widgets within themselves. We create two because we have two different *groups* of `Radiobutton` widgets.

```
var1.set(0)
var2.set(0)
```

Above we set the value of the `StringVar()` variables to be the same as the values of the first `Radiobutton` widgets of each group (which we're about to initialise). This means that when the `Radiobutton`s are drawn, the first one in each group will start selected by default.

```
Radiobutton(root, text = "group1", variable = var1, value = 0).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text = "group1", variable = var1, value = 1).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text = "group2", variable = var2, value = 0).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text = "group2", variable = var2, value = 1).pack()
```

In the above we initialise the `Radiobutton` widgets. We use the `variable` attribute of each `Radiobutton` to assign the variable class associated with each group (`var1` for *group 1* and `var2` for *group 2*) and then we use the `value` attribute to assign the value that the `Radiobutton`s should *"store"* in their associated variables.

This allows us to create 4 `Radiobutton`s in 2 *"groups"* which can update two variables independent of the other *"group"*.